# Proving $\sec^{-1}(z) = -i\log\left[ \frac{1}{z} + \left(\frac{1}{z^2} - 1 \right)^{1/2}\right]$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Prove that
> $$\sec^{-1}(z) = -i\log\left[ \frac{1}{z} + \left(\frac{1}{z^2} - 1 \right)^{1/2}\right]$$

Comment: Do you know how to express the secant in terms of complex exponentials?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Please show the attempts you did to solve your problem.
[How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) 
$-1$ to know why MSE community didn't downvote even after 7Hrs.
*Downvote will be revoked once proper attempts are added*

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints:
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\frac{\cos z+i\sin z+\cos(-z)+i\sin(-z)}{2}=\cos z.
\end{align}
Thus $y(z):=\sec z=\frac{2}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$. Solve for $z$ in terms of $y$ by factoring out $e^{-iz}$ and writing $\alpha=e^{iz}$. We end up solving a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec(x) = z\implies \color{blue}{x = \sec^{-1}z}  \implies z = \frac 2{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}$$
considering princ. value only (Now, we are interested in finding x)

let $$ u = e^{ix} \implies z = \frac 2{u + \frac1u}$$
$$u = \frac {1+ (1-z^2)^{\frac12}}{z}$$
$$\ln u = \ln (e^{ix}) =ix=\ln \left(\frac {1+ (1-z^2)^{1/2}}{z}\right)$$
$$x = \frac1i......$$